# What is ajivika?

Tags: philosophy

I just heard this term from one of my friend. Tried to find more information about it, but no help. Can anyone explain it. Is it Hindu philosophy (as wiki says) or not?

Comment: It means your earnings that you gather from your profession. The profession could be anything a doctor, businessman or even beggars. for example "How do you earn your AJIVIKA ?" -> "How do you earn a living".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80j%C4%ABvika